# Angular not compiling SASS/SCSS files

Tags: angular, sass

Angular CLI is not compiling SCSS files, even when I do `ng build` or `npm run build`.

In the `.angular-cli.json` file I've the following pieces of code required for implementing SCSS, AFAIK.

```
  ...
  "styles": ["styles.css", "../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css"],
  "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": ["app"]
  },
  ...
  ...

  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
```

All my scss files lie inside different component folders but within `app` folder like so, `\src\app\shared\style`. Hence, the `includePaths`.

My folder structure is something like this:

```
MyAngularProject
    |__src
        |__app
            |__styles
                |__app.scss
            |__component1
                |__styles
                    |__component2_Style.scss
            |__component2
                |__styles
                    |__component2_Style.scss
```

How do I get my SCSS files to compile every time `ng serve` or `ng build` is called?

Comment: try to change file extension from `.css` to `.scss`

Comment: i think the path provided is wrong

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: All my SCSS files are with .scss extension. I'm using current Angular CLI so the folder structure is its own. I write my code inside the `src` folder provided by angular cli. Since, I'm using Angular CLI, it must be webpack.

Comment: Do I need to `import './../styles/appStyles.scss';` in all js files?

Comment: Where is appStyles.scss located? It does not show in your code. And are your components referencing their respective componentN_style.scss file?

Comment: Basically, I had used `appStyles.scss` as an example in my above question. What I tried to ask was, whether do I need to include all the `.scss` files in thier related `.ts`/`/js` file?. And yes, each components contain their scss files within themselves as shown in the above directory tree structure

Answer (score 7):

if your scss file is linked in component decorator, then it will automatically compile linked scss to css.

i.e:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
```

and for individual compiling scss check this link 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-with-the-angular-cli

Comment: OK I was putting css files here `styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],` Let me check your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this solved the issue of the asker, but it most certainly solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Mine is linked, and it's not compiling.

Answer (score 0):

The **stylePreprocessorOptions/includePath** config allows you to import your scss file like

```
@import "variables"
```

provided that this files is slocated in a location included in **includePath** instead of having to specify explicitly the file relative path

```
@import "../../styles/variables.scss";
```

However, if you want your styles applied, you still have to explicitly import your scss file.

Depending on what that file contains, either you include it once in your .angular-cli.json, in the **styles** setting (if it contains global styles for your app), or you have to include it in all your scss files if that file to be included contains variables